# Cron Job error says ioncube is not installed when it is

Tags: php, cron, ioncube

I have a website (mivprofit.com) and this website works with a script that requires a couple of cron jobs to run once a day. I have a cron email set and whenever the cron job runs this is the email that I get:

```
Content-type: text/html

Site error: the file <b>/cronpath/ourcron.php</b> requires the ionCube
PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so to be installed by the website
operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a
href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist
with installation.
```

(I actually get two emails, one for each one of the crons, both identical except for the path and file name)

The closest thing I have found to my issue is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/100692/cron-daemon-error-related-to-ioncube). The difference is I don't know what my website is running on and when I go to cpanel>file manager>/etc/ there is no /php5/ folder. However, similarly to that case, my website seems to have ioncube perfectly installed as the entire script requires ioncube to run and it runs perfectly and I am getting the same error as the one in that case. also, the php.ini file is in the same folder as both of the crons and in that same folder there is a phpinfo.php file that, when I open it, says I do have ioncube installed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
I took the time to read through [the possible duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it), however none of those situations seem to be the same as mine. As the problem is not that my command doesn't seem to be running or running properly but it seems to not recognize that ioncube is indeed installed. Thanks [Iain](https://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain) for the information though as now I know a bit more about cron.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: Work your way through the duplicate it will likely help you solve your problem. At worst it will help you gather information that will help us help you. You should edit that into your question.

Comment: Your problem may be that the command line php interpreter is not the same as the one used by your web server ...

Comment: How would I check this? And if this is the case how would I fix it?

Comment: check the for instance the output `phpinfo();` generates for each...

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of IONCUBE(4.1-5.6). Yes you might have it installed properly, but if it's not 5.2 being referenced in the php.ini, your app is not going to work.

I personally had to insert:
zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so

into:

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini - this would be the one most likely used my the cron.

/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Your system admin should be able to get the right one loaded for you.